# Telling a TCP client to seamlessly switch to new server

Tags: tcp

Does TCP have something in place for telling a client "continue this same conversation but at a different address"?

Comment: unfortunately no, you had to use the existing channel to talk. otherwise, you can make something like pooler that "talk" to the "same" server but different ip (logic is done on [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_architecture)). cmiiw.

Comment: oh, i forgot [haproxy](https://serverfault.com/a/549173/321311) can do something like virtual ip (multiple machine listen to packet for the same ip address). haproxy usually used for high availability thingies. but i am not sure it is what you need.

Comment: I would like to be able to transparently switch a client from one node of an auto-scaling system to another dependent on certain factors.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that with TCP.  You would have to make the client close its current connection and open a new connection.  Or else you would need a proxy that can manage multiple connections on its side and switch between them as needed, then have the client connect to the proxy.